# Vuelidate warning in Karma/Chai Testing

Tags: vuejs2, chai

Not that big a deal, but it makes my testing a little ugly. I'm using Vuelidate to handle my data validating, and even though there's no errors in the console for the rendered component I'm testing, my Karma testing is full of these:

```
ERROR LOG: '[Vue warn]: Property or method "$v" is not defined on the
instance but referenced during render Make sure to declare reactive
data properties in the data option. (found in <Root>).'
```

Everything still runs, I'd just like to clean up the error.

Answer (score 1):

Add this intro your test file:

```
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
Vue.use(Vuelidate)
```

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem in my spec file , but using Vue.use in my test is giving this error :ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

Comment: @harmoniuscool, import Vue in spec file before call `Vue.use` method
`import Vue from 'vue'`